# Can anyone help me to optimize this piece of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to store even number and odd number in a separate list. But, here I am facing a unique problem. I am able to store it in sets but not in lists. Is there a way wherein I can store these in a List without repetition.

I have tried this in Jupyter notebook

```
list_loop=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,4,1,51,6,17,]
for i in list_loop:
    if i % 2 == 0 :
        list_even = list_even + [i]
    else:
        list_odd = list_odd + [i]
print(set(list_even))
print(set(list_odd))
```

Expected output:

```
[2,4,6,8,10,12]
[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,17,51]
```

Comment: You haven't said what the actual output is, or why you don't like it.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233355/generating-a-list-of-even-numbers-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `list` function to your `set` object in order to
convert it to a list.

```
list_from_set = list(set(list_even))
>>> print(list_from_set)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. You could use the [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in the collections library, or you could just sort the set and get a list,

```
...
print(sorted(set(list_even)))
print(sorted(set(list_odd)))
```

Also, I would personally create those lists using a set comprehension

```
list_even = sorted({x for x in list_loop if x % 2 == 0})
list_odd = sorted({x for x in list_loop if x % 2 == 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770885/python-set-comprehension)

```
>>> list_loop=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,4,1,51,6,17,]
>>> print(list(set(_ for _ in list_loop if _ % 2)))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 51]
```

Similarly for even numbers.

Comment: I guess he does not want repetitions

Comment: I guess he should specify that, then

Comment: he did. "Is there a way wherein I can store these in a List without repetition."

Answer (score 0):

Define `list_odd` and `list_even` as lists and don't convert them to sets before printing. Note that you can use list comprehension to fill `list_odd` and `list_even`:

```
list_odd = []
list_even = []

list_loop=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,4,1,51,6,17,]
list_odd = [elem for elem in list_loop if elem % 2 != 0]
list_even = [elem for elem in list_loop if elem % 2 == 0]

print(list_even)
print(list_odd)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 4, 6]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 1, 1, 51, 17]
```

Edit: for uniqueness, turn `list_loop` into a set:

```
list_loop=set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,4,1,51,6,17,])
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 51]
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Why use a list comprehension, throw it away while building a new list inside of that same comprehension?

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking there. Edited.

Comment: The expected output indicates that the numbers in the lists should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a list comprehension with a filter condition - *but* you then iterate your list twice.

By using a simple for loop you only need to touch any number *once* at it will conserve the original order - what putting your numbers *through* a set might not do - order in a set is not guaranteed:

Keep a set of `seen` numbers, only add anything if your current number was not yet seen.

```
list_loop = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,4,1,51,6,17,]

list_even = []
list_odd = [] 
seen = set()

trick = [list_even, list_odd]  # even list is at index 0, odd list at index 1

for i in list_loop:
    if i in seen: 
        continue
    else:
        seen.add(i)
                                 # the trick eliminates the need for an if-clause
        trick[i%2].append(i)     # you use i%2 to get either the even or odd index


print(list_even)
print(list_odd)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 51, 17]
```